# Inconsistent Debug Value

Tags: debugging, debug-logs

Debug Log captures all the values once holding maximum Log Size,and subsequent debug value with minimum log Size having no proper value.May I know what causes this issue?Any Help please?Thanks in Advance.

[image: Debug Value]

Comment: Hi Jayasuriya, it's a bit hard to follow what you're asking. Can you include some more detail or examples?

Comment: Can you change the Debug level for System other than fine?? It generates too many logs

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to see actual debug statements, it helps to set all levels to NONE except for System, which should be set at DEBUG. If that's still not good enough, you can also set System to ERROR, and use the alternative debug statement: `System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'This will appear at ERROR or higher');`

Or, you can use [check points](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_checkpoints_setting.htm&type=5). You need to set Apex to INFO or higher. These checkpoints work even if the maximum log size is reached. You can see captured checkpoints in the Developer Console. This will allow you to examine your code's entire memory map at the moment the checkpoint is triggered. This method is strongly recommended, because you can see all of data, not just your debug statements.